# Force Chromium to use different cookie jars per page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, http, google-chrome-devtools

I'm working with Chromium in headless mode, via the [Dev Tools](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot) protocol and I need to implement a system where every page has a totally separate cookie jar that it will use for both JavaScript and HTTP requests.

As far as I can see, this is not supported natively by the browser, and making a hack for it is quite tricky.

If I wanted to control cookies in JavaScript I could overwrite `document.cookie` calls with my own cookie store. If I wanted to control cookies sent via HTTP, I could intercept requests and modify the `Cookie` header and intercept and read the `Set-Cookie` header. The problem is synchronizing the JavaScript with the requests.

Is there a way to do this? If not, how feasible would it be to fork the whole thing, add the feature, and recompile the source code?

Comment: Might be easier to spawn a new headless chrome for a new jar.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm doing.

I'm storing the cookie jar in a node server.I will intercept `Set-Cookie` headers in network requests and update my replacement cookie jar accordingly. I will also modify `Cookie` headers that get sent out to servers accordingly.

The trick is using a synchronous XHR request in order to get and set the cookies from the client, so they're all completely synchronized. Basically, I will overwrite the `document.cookie` property to send synchronous XHR requests to the server in order to get/set the cookies, instead of updating them directly. Almost all requests and all JavaScript will freeze while these operations take place, so there aren't any of the problems that would occur due to async code.